# In SheetsJS, is there a way I can export and import data in the internal SheetsJS format?

Tags: javascript, json, sheetjs

from what I understand, SheetsJS uses an internal data structure, called the SheetJS data model, to internally manage spreadsheets and make them interoperable. I really like how well documented the format is, and how easy it seems to be able to manipulate and do what I want with it. Quite frankly, I'd like to use it as a format to play around with automated spreadsheets, with the full understanding this isn't the intended use case.

There doesn't seem to be any documented method of exporting and importing this format. Are there methods that I could use to do it that I'm just looking at incorrectly?

Presumably I would want to `JSON.stringify` the object to save it, but how would I go about importing it again?

I've mainly been browsing the documentation and have attempted to google several versions of this question, but no avail.

Comment: Have you tried using [sheet_to_json](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities#array-output) to export and [json_to_sheet](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities#array-of-objects-input) to import?